# The name "ViewModelLocator" does not exist in the namespace (universal app)

Tags: windows, mvvm, mvvm-light, win-universal-app

I am developing a universal application that runs both on windows 8.1 and windows phone 8.1.

I am experiencing the error mentioned in the title in the App.xaml file. 
The App.xaml file is in the MyApp.Shared project and so is the ViewModel folder.
However the error ONLY occurs in the Windows 8.1 app. The Windows Phone app runs fine which is very strange as they are running the exact same code.

In the Windows 8.1 app I can't use the ViewModelLocator and its properties so I can't set the DataContext for any of the pages. (The Bindings can't be resolved and the app crashes anytime I try to open a page with a DataContext defined via the ViewModelLocator).

Bellow is my App.xaml File

```
<Application 
x:Class="MyApp.App" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:local="using:MyApp">
<Application.Resources> 
    <ResourceDictionary >
        <!-- This is where the error is -->
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" xmlns:vm="using:MyApp.ViewModel" />
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Colors.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>           
    </ResourceDictionary>       
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

check that your *ViewModelLocator* and *ViewModel* classes has *public* access, after right-click over Windows **project** -> **Clean** , finally **Build**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have seen similar answers that solve this problem this way. In my case however this doesn't work. I also tried compiling for different architectures and I don't get the error for x86 architecture.

What I ended up doing is compiling for x86 in order to have "blendability" and then running it in the device. It works fine that way